# How to follow a custom message format while sending and receiving messages by socket in python?

Tags: python, sockets

The following messages format is to be used for query and response:
Message Type (1 byte)
Length String (1 byte)
Question/Response (<255 bytes)

Message type is going to be "Q" for query and "R" for response. How should I send the message in client side? In the client side, how do I read the first byte to infer message type and the next one byte to infer message size ?

Comment: You should at least make an effort to read a bit about [python sockets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) and give it a try on your own.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I have read the docs and know how to send or receive string messages in form of bytes. What I am struggling with is to make sure the client sends data in the given format where first byte denotes message type, second byte represents length of string, and remaining bytes represent data.

Comment: how about `s.send(b'Q')` for sending the type. Does that make sense?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Does that mean i should send the query multiple times? `s.send(b'Q')` for sending message type, `s.send(bytes(5))` to denote the length of upcoming string is 5 and `s.send(b'abcde')` to send the message? But does this ensure that the first and second sent data are only 1 byte each? I am trying to read this as `query_type = conn.recv(1).decode("utf-8")` Won't this be an issue if the byte size of the character "Q" or "R" is not exactly 1 byte?